# Tab and prompt only has $

Tags: 16.04, command-line, active-directory

in our organisation we have ubuntu systems in domain, due to which we are not able to get the username and hostname in the command prompt instead it just shows the "$" sign when i open the command prompt, also tab does not work for all the commands in ubuntu.

Moreover, when I do sudo su, tab and also command prompt comes.

How to get the username@hostname and tab working in the normal user mode

Thank You in advance.

Comment: The prompt is kept in the `PS1` environment variable. Read `man bash`, especially the `PROMPTING` section - it tells you all the things you can have in your prompt.

Comment: Are you sure the user configuration on the domain server has `bash` as the users' login shell (rather than `sh`)?

Comment: @waltinator you assume that the default for users via Samba / domain auth is actually Bash.  If you don't define the shell to be `/bin/bash` with `useradd` it sets it to Dash, which is just the `$` prompt and tab completion-less.  If `bash` isn't set, `/bin/sh` is the fallback, and that's actually `dash`

Comment: @https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward I assume a POSIX shell - `PS1` is in the POSIX Shell Standard.

Comment: @steeldriver: not sure for this ! do you have any steps to check for that? Currently i go on sudo su, the shell i am getting is /bin/bash but in non-rooted environment it is /bin/sh.

Comment: @ThomasWard: so if we have not defined the shell to be /bin/bash while using the useradd command., how can i do this on ad-hoc basis ?

Comment: @user2041875 Once logged in, you could run `bash` directly, drop yourself into a Bash prompt as you expect.  It's a similar concept, the only thing is you have to first login to the Dash CLI prompt and then run `bash`.  However, that's an extra step to execute; it doesn't solve the core problem of the default shell that new domain users get via Samba

Answer (score 0):

edit your /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file to include:

```
default_shell = /bin/bash
override_shell = /bin/bash
```